# Excluding rows from a model depending on Boolean values in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a post model and user model
The user has a profile page that contains their info and their posts.
The Post model is like this:

```
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Post Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    content = QuillField()
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="post_likes", blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug is None:
            self.slug = slugify(self. Title)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
# views.py
class UserView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, username=None):
        if username == None:
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        else:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)

        posts = Post.objects.filter(owner__username=username).all()

        context = {"user": user, "posts": posts}
        return render(request, "base/user_view.html", context)
```

The user can create a post but can save it as a draft or published it. What I want to achieve is that the user goes to their profile they can see the all their posts that have been published and the ones that have been saved as a draft, but other users can only see the published posts of that user.

How can I achieve this in the profile template? or can it be done in the views.py?

Answer (score 1):

simply add the published condition to the filter:

```
posts_own = Post.objects.filter(owner__username=username)....
posts_others= Post.objects.exclude(owner__username=username).filter(is_published=True)....
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful and gave me insight of how to solve the problem.